# using the channel google app engine from within a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, channel

here is the code that runs in the extension, in the background.html.

```
function onLoad()
{

    var path="http://localhost:8082/index.htm?key=1234";
    xhr.open('get', path, false);
    xhr.send();
    token=xhr.responseText;
    caughtMsg=token+" *** ";
    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
    var handler = {
      'onopen': function(){caughtMsg+=" *** open";},
      'onmessage': onMessage,
      'onerror': function(e){caughtMsg+=" *** err "+e.description+" "+e.code},
      'onclose': function(){caughtMsg+=" *** close";}
    };
    var socket = channel.open(handler);
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;

}
```

it interacts with a localhost server script (in python) that creates a channel and returns a token. then the token is used to create the channel object on the client side.
instead, what i get from the aggregate responses is:

channel-354645736-1234 *** err invalid+token 401 *** close

when i do it outside the extension scope (not using ajax to establish the connection) it works like a charm.

where do i go astray ?

Comment: Are you sure localhost is returning a valid token?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the token is a valid one. as i wrote, when i create the token not in the chrome extension context and not using ajax (doing it like the channel api formal documentation advises), it works just fine.

Comment: Try taking the token generated through the extension and make sure it works outside of the extension context.

Comment: can't be done. the token is generated dynamically on the server side each time a request to open a channel is made

Comment: Just `console.log(token);` in your code and you can use that to open a channel outside of the extension context.

Comment: as much as i know, from the formal documentation, you can't create a channel on the server side using an existing token. the token is a string automatically generated when you create a channel on the server side (it's the return value of the create_channel function on the server side).

Comment: But that is how you are using it here. You generate a token on localhost then open the channel on the client.

Comment: @shayuna Abraham is just suggesting logging the created token to the console, rather than returning it to the client, so you can test it manually.

Comment: i took your advice (thanks). generated the token on the server side and only printed it on the client side, and tried to use it in a different page to create a channel. got the same error. maybe a connection can't be established using ajax, regardless of the chrome extension context. i'm going to test it.

Comment: abraham, you were right. the token wasn't valid. the reason for this was that i used the localhost instead of uploading my app to appspot and going live. when i created my app on appspot and requested the token from the live app, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As i see from your comment, you had problems testing the channel API on your local development system.

It worked for me, when i downloaded the channel.js (instead of using http://*.appspot.com/_ah/channel/jsapi) and used a local copy on the background script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/channel.js"></script>
```

In the channel.js, change the line definining

```
goog.appengine.DevSocket.BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/_ah/channel/";
```

to represent your local environment (port for appengine testserver)

Also, the URL you send your xhr.open to must be in your manifests "permission" section, in my case

```
"permissions":
  [
    ...,
    "http://localhost:8080/"
  ]
```

The tokens generated by your local appengine testserver differ from the ones in the livesystem, so its not possible to mix the two.